# SQL schema optimization, how to avoid unions?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, schema, query-optimization

Imagine that one have the following schema:

[image: SQL Schema]

Now in this schema it will have 10000 fridges, 10000 televisions and 10000 computers. Then it will have 5000 spares for each.
To get all spares related to computers, one would query like this:

```
SELECT SP.name, C.name as computer
FROM spare_parts SP, computer_spare_part CSP, computers C
WHERE   CSP.spare_parts_id = SP.id
AND     CSP.computers_id = C.id
```

Now with a given spare ID = 1, one wants to get the details and the related object(fridge, tv, computer).

```
SELECT SP.name, F.name as equipment
FROM spare_parts SP, fridge_spare_part FSP, fridges F
WHERE   FSP.spare_parts_id = SP.id
AND     FSP.fridges_id = F.id
AND     SP.id = 1

UNION

SELECT SP.name, C.name as equipment
FROM spare_parts SP, computer_spare_part CSP, computers C
WHERE   CSP.spare_parts_id = SP.id
AND     CSP.computers_id = C.id
AND     SP.id = 1

UNION

SELECT SP.name, T.name as equipment
FROM spare_parts SP, television_spare_part TSP, television T
WHERE   TSP.spare_parts_id = SP.id
AND     TSP.televisions_id = C.id
AND     SP.id = 1
```

In this case there are 2 SELECTS that are going to fail. Imagine that spare ID = 1 is related to a computer. The fridge and television SELECT would not get any result.

This will have extra processing time.

How could one optimize this query or schema to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I like this schema.  Did you create it, or was this given to you with the assignment?  I might put all spare parts into a single table.

Comment: Store all of the "products" in one table, with a table for "product type", and table to link products with spare parts. You may also have a table for attributes for products (ie. for "cooling power", "lumens", "processing power").

Comment: @SloanThrasher, in your solution its not possible to get all details(spares and product attributes) only with one query.

Comment: Sure is. Pretty common method to store complex products. Done it plenty of times.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple tables for each product and their respective spare parts is bad idea

> hard to code properly or with a framework, harder to maintain,
>   nightmare to query as well.

So use main tables with same columns and split them accordingly because:

> Divides your information into subject-based tables reduce redundant
>   data. Apply the normalization rules to check it implemented correctly.

In your case, tables should be

```
Product (ProductId, ProductName)
ProductDes(ProductId, ProductType)
SpareParts(productid (FK), sparepart_name, brand)
```

You can enhance them as per requirement now and later without issue. Properly index tables have no issue to process fast.